# Alternative to keyup for pulling value from radio field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to edit a bit of code which is close to working. I want the text to first show "RSVP" but then pull the value of the radio box when someone selects it and uses it as the text of the main text.

https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/7gyrd08w/4/

It nearly works but this code snippet doesn't seem to pick up the value of the radio box. I think it's perhaps because keyup doesn't work on radio fields but I'm not sure how I can get this value.

```
function initInput() {
  input = document.getElementById('input');
  input.addEventListener('keyup', updateText);
  input.value = 'RSVP';
}
```

Comment: You use a mouse on a radio button not a keyboard, you should be using a mouse event like "click"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `change`, this will only trigger when the value changes.

```
function initInput() {
  input = document.getElementById('input');
  input.addEventListener('change', updateText);
  input.value = 'RSVP';
}
```

Edit: I didn't provide an updated fiddle as I assume you can get it working from there.